# Custom token to rename Fields in Template

Tags: custom-field, field

How can we create `custom token` in Sitecore to *rename* the `fields of the template` items at the time of *item creation* ?

I want my *fields* to be *renamed* similar to general link fields present on the template.
Example - If I have *general link field* named *Learn more* and I want to create a `token` which will rename the field as *LearnMoreGTM link*.

I want to do it for at least 4 fields as its the maximum number of general link field we have in our project.
Any thoughts ?

Comment: Sitecore tokens are used to supply value in a field at the time of an item creation. It shall not be used to name the template fields. Template items are not created as often as content items, so they can be named manually the way you want.

Comment: Templates are the Data Structure in the Sitecore and fields are their properties. You can't change anything in the template. Tokens are used for assigning the value to the fields at the time of item creation.

Answer (score 2):

Sitecore tokens are used to populate *field value* and not *field names*. You should define *field names* before creating items from it and use *sections* to keep related fields together.

Fields are like properties in a template, you can't make it dynamic. It is not at all advisable to change field names at the time of item creation.